# Mongodb, Aggregate - How can I use $reverseArray and then use $cond on the returned array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am trying to use $reverseArray and $cond together under $project.
But condition under $cond is not working. I have an array of objects which I want to reverse first and then apply some condition.

Sample database:

```
{
    _id : 1,
    arr:[
       {name : 'a',cf:0 , num : 1},
       {name : 'b',cf:1, , num : 1},
       {name : 'b',cf:0, , num : 2},
       {name : 'a',cf:1, , num : 2},
       {name : 'a',cf:0, , num : 3},
       {name : 'b',cf:1, , num : 3},
       {name : 'a',cf:1, , num : 4}
    ]
}
```

Query I am trying to use:

```
 [
   {
       $project:{reverseArr : {$reverseArray:arr},
                 query1:{$cond :
                 {
                  $if : {
                   $and: [
                    {$eq: ['$reverseArr.name', 'a']},
                    {$eq: ['$reverseArr.cf', 0]}
                   ]
                  },then: 1,else: 0
             }}
        }
   }
 ]
```

So by using above query I want to get the 3rd from the end in the array `{name : 'a',cf:0, , num : 3}`.

But the `$cond` is not matching the required object. I have tried using `$unwind` after `$project` but that did not help me.

What am I doing wrong here? 
How can I achieve what I am trying to do?
Any related question will also help.

Comment: Try using $unwind before the project. You wouldn’t then need the $reverseArray, not sure why you need that?  This will then pull all the elements out of the array for you to then match your $cond on

Comment: Hi @N3i1. I need reversing the array. Can I use 2 `$project` in one aggregate query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you needed to use `$reverseArray` try:

```
 [
   { $project:{reverseArr : {$reverseArray:arr} },
   { $unwind : “reverseArr” },
   { $project:{ query1:{$cond :
             {
              $if : {
               $and: [
                {$eq: ['$reverseArr.name', 'a']},
                {$eq: ['$reverseArr.cf', 0]}
               ]
              },then: 1,else: 0
         }}
    }
 ]
```